# Proxying services through remote with traefik reverse proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel, consul

For my homeserver project I'm hosting multiple services on my local server with services that I want to have outside access to (for example a minecraft game server) port forwarded with reverse ssh tunnels to my remote VPS in order to conceal my residential IP.

Recently I added a traefik (https://traefik.io) instance to my VPS to reverse proxy services that serve a website through my remote server (VPS).
For service discovery, I'm using a local Consul (https://www.consul.io/) instance with Registrator (https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator) and the Consul-catalog backend for traefik.

All services as well as consul and traefik are in docker containers.

What is the best (most secure/performant/convenient) way to proxy all services though the (VPS) without the VPS having access to the LAN?

SSH tunneling has developed some issues along the way (privileged ports, service discovery, TCP only) that make them suboptimal or difficult to set up, I don't want to expose my LAN to the VPS (with a VPN, for example) and I also don't want expose the ports for my services for outside access (mostly security concerns).

Comment: Use a VPN and configure your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Inlets](https://docs.inlets.dev/). It uses WebSockets to securely connect services across networks. It does not require opening ports on the LAN like you would need to do if using a VPN.